# How to deselect any object/objects while selecting multiple objects in Altium designer draftsman

Tags: altium

While editing a draftsman document in Altium designer, I can select multiple objects using Shift+left click, and using the mouse cursor. But while selecting multiple objects using the mouse cursor I need to exclude some objects. For example, in the Image, all the lines and arcs are selected. How can I exclude the arcs while remaining the lines selected?

In windows explorer, we can deselect some files or folders using ctrl + click. Are there any similar functions here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/shortcut-keys-draftsman-editor

```
Shift+Click       On an object to add it to the current selection (cumulative selection).
```

The selection is cumulative on click, but not subtractive thereafter. I can't see a reason for this and it also frustrates me that common commands we all know are not universal.

A workaround you might benefit from is a separate keyboard shortcut - 'S' then 'T'

**S**elect > **T**oggle Selection

Your cursor will change to a small crosshair and you can select/deselect items at will, both cumulatively and subtractively

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shift + Click normally changes the selection status of an object, without changing that of others.

This means that if you Shift + Click on a selected object it'll be de-selected.

Comment: Currently using Altium designer 21.5.1, the Shift  + Click to de-select works on schematic docs but not working on draftsman documents.